# mysqli->query delete didn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$mysqli=new mysqli($sqlhost,$sqlusername,$sqlpw,$sqldbname);
    $mysqli_del=new mysqli($sqlhost,$sqlusername,$sqlpw,$sqldbname);
    if($delete_image){
        $image_in_album=$mysqli->query("select * from albums_detail where albumid='$albumid'");
        while($row=$image_in_album->fetch_assoc()){
            $imgid=$row['imgid'];
            $mysqli_del->query("delete from imgs where imgid='$imgid'");//Not work
            unlink('data/imgs/'.$imgid);
            unlink('data/thumbs/'.$imgid);
        }
    }
    $mysqli->query("delete from albums_detail where albumid='$albumid'");
    $mysqli->query("delete from albums where albumid='$albumid' and userid='$userid'");
    $mysqli->close();
```

the line

> $mysqli_del->query("delete from imgs where imgid='$imgid'");

not working? What's wrong?

Comment: If you checked for error you'd know

Comment: Why instantiate two times?

Comment: unlink line is working. I don't know why the delete query not working

Comment: I'm instantiate two times because when i search the problem i finded same connection will not work in fetch_assoc. and one instantiate not working too

Comment: Well, without any msqli error checking in place, it's harder to diagnose. I would suggest looking into that.

Comment: This is a sql error. I has found it. I try delete table imgs before delete Foreign key in albums_detail. Thank for help